# How should I change all my products' availability to true in django oscar?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I'm slowly getting familiar with overriding things in oscar, but in this case I'm still not sure what and where to override to achieve my goal.

So when I'm trying to add a product to basket, it will check if it's available at ../api/product/n/availability which returns something like this:

```
{
    "is_available_to_buy": false,
    "message": "Unavailable"
}
```

Since I personally don't need to check for availability, I just want it to return true in every case, for which I thought about these solutions: https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/_modules/oscar/apps/partner/strategy.html#Structured

Here, in the first function under **Structured**, I could change is_available_to_buy to true

Or

https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-api/blob/master/oscarapi/serializers/product.py

I could override **AvailabilitySerializer** to return true by default.

I wonder if any of these could be overridden, and if yes, how exactly do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for those who need help you can use [Django import-Export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
and you can override the save method to export all products and edit the availability field to True and import to database.